# Spring, веб приложение, запуск метода по кнопке на сайте

Tags: spring

Есть метод, который долго выполняется, например 3 часа. Как мне запустить этот метод, закрыть интернет страничку и не ждать его выполнения?
Метод должен продолжить выполнение с закрытой страничкой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простейший пример:

```
package com.test.userservice.controller

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class TestController{

    @GetMapping("/test")
    fun test() : String {
        var one = object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                try {
                    veryLongMethod()
                    veryLongMethod()
                    veryLongMethod()
                } catch (v: InterruptedException) {
                    println(v)
                }
            }
        }
        one.start()
        return "test";
    }

    fun veryLongMethod() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L)
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        println("long method: thread name " + Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
}
```

Как только придет запрос по роутингу /test, то будет создан отдельный поток, в котором выполнится метод veryLongMethod 3 раза. При этом http запрос не будет ждать никакого результата и выведет сообщение "test" сразу на экран.